# Getting variables between slash forwards in a URL

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

Let's say I have a URL: `https://somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html` How would I get these variables: `/0/, /20/, /290/` ? Note they are variables, they will always be different.

I thought I could get them like so:

`$url = '//somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html';
var_dump(parse_url($url));`

but the array doesn't show them as separate variables. Should it be done with a `preg_replace` instead? I don't think I know how. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use explode() and turn the string into an array divided by the "/" delimiter.

```
<?php
// Example 1
$url  = "https://somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html";
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
echo $pieces[0] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[1] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[2] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[3] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[4] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[5] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[5] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[6] . "<br />";
echo $pieces[7] . "<br />";

echo "<hr />";
// Example 2
$data = "https://somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html";
list($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth) = explode("/", $url);
echo $first . "<br />";
echo $second . "<br />";
echo $third . "<br />";
echo $fourth . "<br />";
echo $fifth . "<br />";
echo $sixth . "<br />";
echo $seventh . "<br />";
echo $eighth . "<br />";

?>
```

Output:

```
https:

somesite.com
0
posts
20
20
290
755653-Title.html
```

---

```
https:

somesite.com
0
posts
20
290
755653-Title.html
```

Comment: I love it! This is what I wanted, actually. Will try all of them. I went from not having options to too many! :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually answer the original question.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a positive lookahead with [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) where you capture the pattern in a capturing group:

```
(?=(/\d+/))
```

That will match

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `(/\d+/)` Match `/`, 1+ digits and `/`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Uj0tT/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/bSet1)

For example

```
$re = '~(?=(/\d+/))~m';
$str = 'https://somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => /0/
    [1] => /20/
    [2] => /290/
)
```

If you want to get the digits only without the surrounding slashes you could add the group around the digits only

```
(?=/(\d+)/)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/9cgPi)

Comment: Awesome. One more question, how would I echo / get them separately? What, for instance, /20/ will be in this array?

Comment: Do you mean you want `/`, `0` and `/` separately in an array?

Comment: No, I mean I want to use them like $a, $b, $c. But I am not sure how to get them from the array and use them separately if need be.

Comment: @VitaliKloster You could access the values by index like `$a =  $matches[1][0];` and `$b = $matches[1][1];`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can try splitting on path separator, and then using `array_filter` with an inline function to retain only purely numerical components:

```
$str = 'https://somesite.com/0/posts/20/290/755653-Title.html';
$parts = explode("/", $str);
$parts = array_filter($parts, function($item) { return is_numeric($item); });
print_r($parts);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 0
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 290
)
```

Note that this approach completely avoids the use of a formal regex, which might have performance implications if you needed to do this often in your script.